# How to "describe" a column in pandas for python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas in python and I have a dataframe where one column is a timestamp and others contain data.[image: Example]

The blue line stays constant for a while, then suddenly increases to zero, then at some point descends again to about -98 and stays there until it suddenly goes up to zero. What I need is a new column with the status of the blue color: constant,sudden increase, constant, decrease, constant, sudden increase, constant or somehow an object that describes the data:

```
blue line{ 
'08.02.2022 08:30:00.000' : 'sudden increase',
'08.02.2022 10:39:30.000' : 'start decrease',
'08.02.2022 10:59:40.000' : 'end decrease',
'08.02.2022 13:50:30.000' : 'sudden increase' 
}
```

Is there a package for something like this? I hope it isn't too far feched

Kind Regards, Alexander

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset to play with?

Comment: @mozway http://www.fyrobe-club-sisseln.ch/stuff/test.xlsx

Comment: thanks! here is my [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035956/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> constant,sudden increase, constant, decrease, constant, sudden
> increase, constant

Then I suggest taking looking at [`numpy.gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), consider following simple example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,5,3,1])
arrg = np.gradient(arr)
for a,g in zip(arr,arrg):
    print(a,g,sep=",")
```

output

```
0,0.0
0,0.0
0,0.5
1,1.0
2,1.0
3,1.0
4,1.0
5,1.0
6,1.0
7,0.5
7,0.0
7,0.0
7,0.0
7,-1.0
5,-2.0
3,-2.0
1,-2.0
```

Observe that constant parts result in zeros (potentially excluding these point adjacent to increase/decrease), increase result in positive values, decrease result in negative values, more increase/decrease the more value is far from zero.

You might need to convert `pandas.Series` (column of `pandas.DataFrame`) into `numpy.array` - for which `pandas.Series` sports method `.to_numpy`.

**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that your data are evenly spaced, e.g. from sensor providing value each second.

Edit in order to detect borders of increase/decrease you might leverage [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) following way, using `arr` and `arrg` from example above

```
arrb = abs(np.diff(arrg)) > 0.01
for a,b in zip(arr,arrb):
    print(a,b,sep=",")
```

output

```
0,False
0,True
0,True
1,False
2,False
3,False
4,False
5,False
6,True
7,True
7,False
7,False
7,True
7,True
5,False
3,False
```

Beware that due to how `numpy.diff` work you will get result shorter by 1 observation.

This does compute difference between adjacent elements then checks if it is absolute value is greater than `0.01` (you might need to adjust value depending on your data), when there is `True` (possibly few adjacent `True`s) there is kink.

Comment: that's also the approach I would use. You can use the x-values if needed to compute the gradient ;)

Comment: What I primarily need is the start and end point of the gradient

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your data looks like.

In blue the data, in red the gradient. As the time interval is uniform, you can directly use the `diff` to compute the gradient (here clipped to a max of 1).

[image: data]

Now you can use `numpy.select` to map thresholds in the gradient to your labels.

Then, in pandas it is easy to filter the rows by changes in labels:

```
# input data
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx').set_index('time')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# compute gradient
grad = df['Col1'].diff()
# set labels
thresh_sudden = 10
thresh_gradual = 0.25
df['state'] = np.select([grad>thresh_sudden, grad<-thresh_gradual],
                        ['sudden increase', 'start decrease'],
                        'constant')  # default

# add end of decrease
df.loc[df['state'].eq('start decrease') & df['state'].shift(-1).eq('constant'),
       'state'] = 'end decrease'

# find changing points
change = df['state'].ne(df['state'].shift())
df['change'] = df['state'].where(change)

# slice
df[change]
```

output:

```
                      Col1      Col2            state           change
time                                                                  
2022-08-02 08:00:00 -98.05       NaN         constant         constant
2022-08-02 08:29:50 -96.99       NaN  sudden increase  sudden increase
2022-08-02 08:30:10  -0.01       NaN         constant         constant
2022-08-02 10:39:30  -0.89  1.351546   start decrease   start decrease
2022-08-02 10:59:20 -97.86  1.415426     end decrease     end decrease
2022-08-02 10:59:30 -98.04  1.415426         constant         constant
2022-08-02 13:50:20 -98.09  0.441630  sudden increase  sudden increase
2022-08-02 13:50:50  -0.12  0.441630         constant         constant
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure this will work :)

Comment: @AlexanderWeixelbaumer have you tested it with your real data? Don't hesitate to give feedback ;)

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you very much